# How do I get a direction vector from a dregree [0°, 360°)

Tags: vectors

Given an interval of degrees in $[0^\circ,360^\circ)$

I would like to know the direction vector from **any degree** from that interval. 
So the $225^\circ$ in the picture is just an example.

How can you do such thing?

[image]

Comment: How familiar are you with trigonometry? Not that you need much of it in the specific case of $225^\circ$, but it is necessary in general.

Comment: @Arthur I have tried this with tan but I was entangled by thinking i'm on the wrong path

Comment: is that an $a$ or a 

Answer (score 1):

In general, right triangle trigonometry gives us $x=v\cos(a)$ and $y=v\sin(a)$.

This means that the vector with direction $a$ and magnitude $v$ is $\begin{bmatrix} v\cos(a)\\ v\sin(a) \end{bmatrix}$.

For vectors you really only need to know this much. But make sure you understand basic trigonometry because it'll be useful!

Comment: "a" is in radian in this case, right?

Comment: this is only applicable to $\sin$, $\cos$ functions' domain - so just be consistent

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you draw a line from the tip of the vector you get a right triangle with width $v_x$, height $v_y$ and hypotenuse $\|v\|$. Now use the definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$ to deduce
$$
\sin\alpha = \frac{v_y}{\|v\|},\quad\cos\alpha = \frac{v_x}{\|v\|}\\
v_x = \|v\|\sin\alpha,\quad v_y = \|v\|\cos\alpha
$$
For $\alpha$ larger than $90^\circ$, the definitions of $\sin$ and $\cos$ are extended to make the signs in the above equations match up, so that you don't have to worry about it; it happens on its own.